# Display quotient using System.out.printf in java

Tags: java

```
    float a, b;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 2 integer");
    System.out.println("Enter first integer");
    a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second integer");
    b = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Calculation the sum, difference, product, quotient "
            + "of 2 integer");
    System.out.printf("Sum of 2 integer is: %f\n", a + b);
    System.out.printf("Difference of 2 integer is: %f\n", a - b);
    System.out.printf("Product of 2 integer is: %f\n", a * b);
    System.out.printf("Quotient of 2 integer is: %0.2f\n", a / b);
```

This is my code for this and program  run error. So I want to display like this a = 7, b = 5 so a/b= 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
System.out.printf("Quotient of 2 integer is: %0.2f\n", a / b);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("Quotient of 2 integer is: %.2f\n", a / b);
```

Comment: The cast to `double` is not necessary. Just fix the format string. And input is not casted to int, but an exception is thrown if a non-int input is encountered.